# Why is .then() not a function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I am working on bar graph using d3 in javascript. Basically I am provided with some json data that contains the information for the graph. What I believe is happening is that for some reason the `.then()` method is not grabbing the json info and working it into the rest of the code, but nor is the catch statement working. When I inspect the page in the console, it displays the error message, "Uncaught TypeError: d3.json(...).then is not a function."

The example that I was provided with works flawlessly. I haven't copied the example completely, but as I am still new to d3 and have had difficulty with javascript in general, I have initially sampled the code quite heavily with the intention of trying to rework it to make it my own, but I cannot seem to get past this `.then()` method error. Any help would be greatly appreciated (I've asterisked the `.then()` statement below).

Here is my code:

```
let width = 1000;
let height = 500;
let barWidth = width / 270;

var svgContainer = d3
    .select('.graph-box')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + 120)
    .attr('height', height + 75);

var tooltip = d3
    .select('.graph-box')
    .append('div')
    .attr('id', 'tooltip');

var overlay = d3
    .select('.graph-box')
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'overlay');

 **d3.json(  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json')
  .then((data) => {**
    svgContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(- 90)')
      .attr('x', -200)
      .attr('y', 100)
      .text('Gross Domestic Product')
      .style('font-size', 18);
  
    svgContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr('x', width + 100)
      .attr('y', height + 50)
      .text("Source: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json'")
      .attr('class', 'source-info');
  
    var years = data.data.map(function(val) {
      var quarter;
      var month = val[0].substring(5, 7);
      
      if (month === '01') {
        quarter = 'Q1';
      }
      else if (month === '04') {
        quarter = 'Q2';
      }
      else if (month === '07') {
        quarter = 'Q3';
      }
      else if (month === '10') {
        quarter = 'Q4';
      }
      return val[0].substring(0, 4) + ' ' + quarter; 
    });
  
  var byYear = data.data.map(function(val) {
    return new Date(val[0]);
  });
  
  var xAxisMax = new Date(d3.max(byYear));
  xAxisMax.setMonth(xAxisMax.getMonth() + 3);
  var xScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain([d3.min(byYear), xAxisMax])
    .range([0, width])
  
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);
  
  svgContainer
    .append('g')
    .call(xAxis)
    .attr('id', 'x-axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(60, 400)');
  
  var GDP = data.data.map(function(val) {
    return val[1];
  });
  
  let scaledGDP = [];
  
  var GDPmax = d3.max(GDP);
  
  var xAxisScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, GDPmax]).range([0, height]);
  
  scaledGDP = GDP.map(function(val) {
    return xAxisScale(val);
  });
  
  var yAxisScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, GDPmax]).range([height, 0]);
  
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yAxisScale);
  
  svgContainer
    .append('g')
    .call(yAxis)
    .attr('id', 'y-axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(60, 0)')
  
  d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(scaledGDP)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('data-date', function(d, i) {
      return data.data[i][0];
  })
    .attr('data-gdp', function(d, i) {
      return data.data[i][1];
  })
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
       return xScale(byYear[i]); 
  })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return (height - d);
  })
    .attr('width', barWidth)
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return d;
  })
    .attr('index', (d, i) => i)
    .style('fill', '#375AFA')
    .style('transform', 'translate(60, 0)')
    .on('mouseover', function(event, d) {
      var i = this.getAttribute('index');
    
        overlay
           .transition()
           .duration(0.5)
           .style('height', d + 'px')
           .style('width', barWidth + 'px')
           .style('opacity', 0.75)
           .style('left', i * barWidth + 0 + 'px')
           .style('top', height - d + 'px')
           .style('transform', 'translateX(75px)');
  
    tooltip
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style('opacity', 0.75);
    
    tooltip
      .html(years[i] + '<br>' + '$' + 
           GDP[i].toFixed(1).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,') + ' billion')
      .attr('data-date', data.data[i][0])
      .style('left', i * barWidth + 30 + 'px')
      .style('top', height - 100 + 'px')
      .style('transform', 'translateX(75px)');
    })
      .on('mouseout', function() {
        tooltip
          .transition()
          .duration(200);
        
        overlay
          .transition()
          .duration(200);
    });  
})
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Is this D3 v5 or above?

Comment: When I checked after reading this I realized that I had the `<script>` tag in the html linked to v3. Feeling quite stupid now, but thank you. I set it to v7 and it works just fine. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @StandAlone2323 if you problem is solved, please close the question.

Comment: Would if i could

Comment: @StandAlone2323 you should now be able to answer your own question, which might be helpful to others with similar questions in the future.